# Bash - how to get a list of git branches?

Tags: bash, git

I am working on a bash script that searches for git branches and lists them out:

```
# Search for a branch by name.
gbs () {
  branches=`git branch --list $1*`
  branches_len=${#branches[@]}
  echo "$branches_len branches found:"
  for branch in $branches
  do
   printf "$branch\n"
  done
}
```

The output is:

```
joe.bloggs$ gbs X
1 branches found:
XX/test1
XX/test2
```

Why is it just showing 1 branch found, when it is iterating the array and finding 2 branches?

Answer (score 2):

The `git branch` command is meant for interactive shell purpose only.
It has fancy formatting, layout and highlights, that makes it easier to read for a human-being; but it turns into a bug-trap, as soon as one tries to parses it from a script.

Because it does not provide a consistent stable and programmatically friendly output format; it cannot be relied upon, for parsing its output with a shell script.

The common and stable Git API entry point for most shell scripting needs, is the `git for-each-ref` command.

So! Here your branch search function can be simplified, and made significantly more reliable using `git for-each-ref` rather than `git branch`:

```bash
gbs() {
  git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:strip=2)' "refs/heads/$1"
}
```

Or if you want to search for all patterns provided as arguments:

```bash
gbs() {
  git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:strip=2)' "${@/#/refs\/heads\/}"
}
```

---

For nice and portable bash/zsh git boilerplate functions examples, with mostly the [same branch search function for bash completion](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L639-L650) that what I wrote above for you; see:
https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found the correct syntax:

```
# Search for a branch by name.
gbs () {
  branches=(`git branch --list $1*`)
  branches_len=${#branches[@]}
  echo "$branches_len branches found:"
  for branch in ${branches[@]}
  do
   printf "$branch\n"
  done
}
```

Comment: You don't use `git branch`, because it is not designed with a stable API format for plumbing a script. You use `git for-each-ref` instead and straight gets a one-line very short function for the same purpose: `gbs(){ git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:lstrip=2)' "refs/heads/$1";}`